# printf prints unexpected last element of a multidimensional array in C, depending on input?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm learning to use multidimensional arrays in C and I'm unable to understand why `printf()` sometimes gives an unexpected result in the following program.

The idea in this program is that I wish to initialize a 5x2 array and accept 5 integers from the user with `scanf` to populate the 2nd index, then print the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0, mat[5][2] = {
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0}
    };

    printf("Please enter 5 integers then press enter: \n");

    do {
        scanf("%i", &mat[i][2]);
        i++; 
       } while (getchar() != '\n');


    printf("Here's what the 5x2 array looks like: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%i %i", mat[i][1], mat[i][2]);
        printf(" \n");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

If I enter certain integers as the user, then the output is as expected:

```
C:\Users\hackr>tmp.exe
Please enter 5 integers then press enter:
0 1 2 3 4
Here's what the 5x2 array looks like:
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
```

However, if I enter different integers, then the last line of output is not what I expected:

```
C:\Users\hackr>tmp.exe
Please enter 5 integers then press enter:
1 2 3 4 5
Here's what the 5x2 array looks like:
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 4

C:\Users\hackr>tmp.exe
Please enter 5 integers then press enter:
9 8 7 6 5
Here's what the 5x2 array looks like:
0 9
0 8
0 7
0 6
0 4
```

In fact, as you can see above, it looks like the final element of index 2 is arbitrarily "4".

Perhaps this is due to a misunderstanding on my part regarding how the array values are indexed or referenced?

Comment: `scanf("%i", &mat[i][2])` is out of bounds for `mat[5][2]`.

Comment: @cnicutar it is? I've been trying to understand this. I understand that arrays are 0-indexed, however it seemed like when declaring their size I am supposed to type the actual number of elements like `int mat[5][2]` for a 5x2 array? Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always the array starts with the index 0.

You can try the following snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0, mat[5][2] = {
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0}
    };

    printf("Please enter 5 integers then press enter: \n");

    do {
        scanf("%i", &mat[i][1]);
        i++; 
       } while (getchar() != '\n');


    printf("Here's what the 5x2 array looks like: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%i %i", mat[i][0], mat[i][1]);
        printf(" \n");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

while declaration you can use mat[5][2], but for access you should use

```
mat[0][0] mat[0][1]
mat[1][0] mat[1][1]
...
..
mat[4][0] mat[4][1]
```

I think now it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I tried the assumption of 0-based indexing in the second index before with bad results, but clearly I had some other confounding mistake in the code. +1   One follow up question -- why did it appear to work when I entered the input as `0 1 2 3 4`?

Comment: The reason is that the matrix allocation is done using the hex decimal ranges of the computer architecture. In the case yours, C programming guarantees you all the matrix elements will be stored in the following format:
mat[0][0] - in address (&mat) till mat[4][1] in &(mat+9).

You tried to store element beyond the allocated location using its own address and tried to access with un-allocated address. Hence computer decides whether to store the value in the particular location or not. The location that gave wrong result is &(Mat+11) is  outside the range of allocation..

Answer (score 2):

`mat` is defined as:

```
int mat[5][2];
```

Valid elements are `mat[x][y]` for `x` in range 0 ~ 4 and `y` in range 0 ~ 1, while you are trying to access out of bound elements in

```
scanf("%i", &mat[i][2]);
```

and

```
printf("%i %i", mat[i][1], mat[i][2]);
```

Comment: and `scanf("%i", &mat[i][2]);` is out of bounds too

Comment: Thank you. I thought I tried the assumption of 0-based indexing in the second index before with bad results, but clearly I had some other confounding mistake in the code. +1